# MVC Controller Query Result not displaying in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to sort a database table and display the results in a View in MVC.
The  query in the Controller returns the sorted results in a console application (which references the same database)  but the list displays as unsorted in the View. What am I doing wrong/ missing?

```
     public class HomeController : Controller 

{
    private SwimTimesEntities db = new SwimTimesEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
                var query = from s in db.Swims
                    orderby s.Day
                    select s; 

        return View(query.ToList());
    }
```

And the Model is

```
    public partial class Swim
{
    public int SwimID { get; set; }
    public System.TimeSpan Time { get; set; }

    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

}

(Very) New to C# and MVC, pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `View` try using a `Model`, for sample:

```
@model List<Swim>

<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <li>@item.Day - @item.Detail</li>
}
</ul>
```